# Which XPath expression should I use for XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode when the document has no namespace?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I have some XML that has been generated by default conversion of a JSON response stream, and so doesn't have a namespace declared. I now want to retrieve a specific node from that XML by using the SelectSingleNode method, but cannot specify the namespace because there isn't one specified. What should I use to register a namespace?

My XML looks like this:

```
<root type="object">
  <customer type="object">
    <firstName type="string">Kirsten</firstName>
    <lastName type="string">Stormhammer</lastName>
  </customer>
</root>
```

The code I have tried is:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(customerXml);

XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/");    // What should I use here?

XmlNode customerNode= document.SelectSingleNode("x:customer");
```

This always returns null.

I have also tried using the local-name qualifier (without using a namespace manager):

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(customerXml);

XmlNode customerNode= document.SelectSingleNode("/*[local-name()='root']/*[local-name()='customer']");
```

This also returns null.

Comment: 1) have you tried just "customer" without adding a namespace.  2) if possible take a look at Linq to XML, it's a much better XML DOM.

Comment: No clue of C#, but why not just do away with the Namespace Manager if there is no namespace?

Comment: I had tried just "customer", without a namespace, but this wasn't working because I needed the full path, "/root/customer". I had assumed the problem was because I wasn't using the namespace manager, which is why I tried that. Now resolved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you can do in a much simpler way, without involving `XmlNamespaceManager` and namespace prefix :

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(customerXml);

XmlNode customerNode= document.SelectSingleNode("/root/customer");
```

**[[.NET fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HAT15M)]**

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer. My problem was not including the root element in the XPath.